# How to make browser window not minimizable, always on top and have it on a corner of the OS by any means necessary(javascript/html/C#)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser

We have any existing web application and our client wants us to make the it run always on top of the operating system and non-minimizable, by any means necessary?

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYgo5.png)

I tried looking for a solution on the internet of html/javascript/chrome setting having control over the window but so far, no luck.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible (thankfully), at least not without writing your own browser (or possibly extension) that hooks into the operating system

Comment: How about chrome settings?

Comment: Not possible. Chrome doesn't have any settings like that. If it did, the user could change them, so even if they existed, they'd be useless.

Comment: Any third party programs which we can integrate with the application on startup?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (consistently). Deliberately malicious actions are generally restricted by browsers.